# Why do I get a 'None' in the title of the legend when plotting a pivot_table?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table

I have a dataframe and then I call the `pivot_table` method and then plot the result.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2020-04-10', '2020-04-11', '2020-04-12', '2020-04-13','2020-04-10', '2020-04-11', '2020-04-12', '2020-04-13'],
'Station': ['Hogwarts', 'Hogwarts', 'Hogwarts', 'Hogwarts','Hogwarts', 'Hogwarts', 'Hogwarts', 'Hogwarts'],
'Direction': ['Southbound', 'Southbound', 'Southbound', 'Southbound','Northbound','Northbound','Northbound','Northbound'],
'Daily trains': [1,1,2,3,0,0,2,1]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format="%Y-%m-%d")

df1 = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns=['Station','Direction'],values=['Daily trains'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

df1.plot(ax=ax)
ax.figure.savefig('so.png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

Here it is the result:

[image]

Why do I get a `'None'` in the title of the legend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It labels the column names.

```
df1.columns.names
#FrozenList([None, 'Station', 'Direction'])
```

You provide a `list` of values but you only have one value so it creates an unnecessary level in your columns MultiIndex. Remove the `[]`.

...

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns=['Station','Direction'], values='Daily trains')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
df1.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

---

If you need to pivot multiple columns, (i.e. `values = ['Daily Trains', 'Daily Accidents']`), and want to plot all of them then you'll still be stuck with `None` for that level's name. You can rename it to something before plotting.

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.rename('Category', level=0)
```